# Assembly PEP8 - Problem with program execution (DECI instruction)

Tags: assembly, pep8

I read various exemple and the DECI instruction seems to be straight forward, it waits for a decimal number and store it in the register.

I'm trying to make a program that starts by outprinting a message (with STRO) and wait for a decimal input, then output the decimal.

It doesn't wait to the decimal input, it's as if it reads automatically the empty input before having the time to enter any value.

The problem is that as soon as I start the program, the output is: 
Saisissez un numéro de carte de crédit à valider de 8 chiffres.
ERROR: Invalid DECI input

Here is my program

```
BR main

message: .ASCII "Saisissez un numéro de carte de crédit à valider de 8 chiffres.\x00"

msg_err: .ASCII "Le chiffre n'est pas valide\x00" 

msg_val: .ASCII "Résultat de l'étape 3:La carte est valide\x00" 

msg_inva: .ASCII "Résultat de l'étape 3:La carte est invalide\x00" 

number: .BLOCK 1  

somme: .WORD 0

FINLIGNE:.EQUATE 0x000A



main: STRO message,d 

DECI number,d 

CHARO FINLIGNE,i 

LDA number, d

DECO number,d

STOP

.END
```

Is there an instruction to place to make the program wait before the DECI instructions? I have gone through a good amounts of instructions and I'm not finding anything that applies to this situation. STOP instructions simply stops the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally that means something was left in the input buffer from previous operations. Does not apply in your case since this seems to be the first and only input instruction in the code. There seems to be something wrong with your environment. Works fine for me.

Comment: By work fine do you mean that you tried my program and after the message, it waits for the decimal input, then outprint the decimal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it.